# Grafana - Config overridden from Environment variable

Tags: docker, environment-variables, grafana

I'm trying to follow [Configure with environment variables](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/configuration/#configure-with-environment-variables) / [root_url](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/configuration/#root-url)

```
# grep GF_ROOT_URL docker-compose.override.yml 
                        - GF_ROOT_URL=https://g.x.com/
#
```

yet, when I invite users into Grafana, they're getting invited to `localhost` (instead of root_url) in their invitation...

Please advise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable name is `GF_<SectionName>_<KeyName>`, so it's `GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL`, not `GF_ROOT_URL`:

```
# grep ROOT_URL docker-compose.override.yml 
                        - GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=https://g.x.com/
#
```